# Is it acceptable to re-use a constant across different packages?

Tags: java

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question. I have also checked related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348454/best-practices-to-define-constants-used-in-an-app) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305727/string-constants-vs-resource-bundle-in-an-java-web-application) but it is not exactly the same thing.

The question is really simple, let's say that we have somewhere on our application a constant defined like this:

```
public static final String CONSTANT_NAME = "My Constant";
```

And in a different package, we also need the same constant. Is it acceptable (aka good practice) to reuse the existing one or should we create a new one (and then declare both as private/protected if applicable)?

I am talking about constants used in the application like key names to retrieve from Collections, not internationalization constants.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see an issue. Since it is public, the authors (hopefully) are aware that this can be directly used by clients

Comment: If it is something common for several things, maybe it makes sense to extract it to a separate class (enum) and use that wherever you need? E.g. `public class AppConstants { /* keep all the constants you are using in the app here */  }`

Comment: Why not? Eventually to not get confused you can create an package with commons things.

Comment: If you decided that a constant is indeed what you really want to use then reusing it where applicable is what you should be doing even imho. Why create redundancy.

Comment: Using a general constant is prefered over always writing `"My Constant"`, because once you have to refactor the value that is used you're in a big mess

Comment: it's a constant. why would you declare it over and over and over again? Do you think the value of public static final int ONE = 1; might be different in another package?

Comment: I think there may be cases where it makes sense to declare more than one constant with the same value, e.g. if those values are only the same by coincidence, but might change (for one of the clients) in the future. But, in general, not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is going be highly dependent on the context.  You would need to consider things like:

- Do the constants mean the same thing in the different places where you are declaring them?
- Are the shared constants part of a common API?  Or are they intended to provide a degree of uniformity across a number of related APIs?
- Are there modularity concerns?  Does exposing the constants across multiple packages (or Java 9+ modules) cause *undesirable*<sup>1</sup> coupling?

You should weigh up the competing factors / concerns and come to your own conclusions.  And don't be overly afraid to revise / refactor if you have reasons to regret your choices<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Not all coupling is bad.  There is a tension between coupling and other things ... like code reuse.</sup>

<sup>2 - Modulo the potential impact that the refactoring might have on important APIs ... and other people's code.</sup>

Answer (score -4):

No it’s not acceptable to define a constant and use in different packages. Because it violates the loose coupling principle. 
If you want to move your classes or packages to another project then because of this kind of tight coupling you also should move the constant residing package.

Comment: this is nonsense. are you going to prefer new BigInteger("10") over BigInteger.TEN because you're in a different package?

Comment: By the same reasoning, it is not good practice to re-use classes defined in other packages.

Comment: So we're in fact not allowed to use third party libraries, but implement everything ourselfs, because they're always declared inside other packages :/

Comment: I was talking about custom defined  bussiness related classes. I saw bad practices where all class related constants which logically belongs to different classes collected inside a huge constant holding classes.

Comment: @Lino its not about using third party libraries, its about your project and class design.

Comment: @Stultuske check the question he said key names not internationalization related or so general constants

Comment: But you are writing "not acceptable to reuse one constant from package A in package B", you are not writing "not acceptable to put all your constants into a single class or package".

Comment: @Stultuske also defining such a constant public and using all over the project is not a good idea. You should use the constant residing class

Comment: @tobias_k in question he/she said that not like internalitazion but key names like constants.

Comment: @ahmettolga he said "Constants" not "Constants that only make sense in this class". Why would he want to consider re-using them in a different class unless they are identical and have the same meaning?
As per your last statement: the BigInteger class is bad because it offers constants? I assume you want to implement your very own value for TEN?

Comment: "Constants that only make sens in this class?" every constant make sense in the class where constant belongs to, i al also saying keeping constants where they are belong to not spreading meaningless. Its not about implementing your own value of TEN class.

Comment: @ahmettolga so you're completly fine declaring the same constant 3 times just to not spread them?

Comment: If you are declearing same constant 3 times than you are doing something wrong. You should be using if needed constant residing class.